# how check radio button status in oracle form

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I like to control a radio button in my oracle form.
please help me how I can return its value please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any Forms item, you can get the current value by referencing:

```
:MYBLOCK.MYITEM
```

(assuming you have a radio group called MYITEM in a block called MYBLOCK).